# Best design pattern for a mixed collection in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, subclass

I have a collection of items they all share some data (like an id, title) however outside of their shared stem of attributes they're functionally unique items and have separate views and business logic.

My problem is without prior experience in Backbone style MVC, I don't know the pros / cons of each... or perhaps if there is a much more elegant solution I'm missing.  Here's an example of the 3 techniques I could potentially use?

```
var gizmoCollection = new Backbone.Collection(); // or extend
var gizmoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });

var morgView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });
var blarView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });


// 1.)  Create an attribute for the view in the model?
gizmoCollection.add(new gizmoModel({ title: 'Gizmo1': view: morgView }));
gizmoCollection.add(new gizmoModel({ title: 'Gizmo2': view: blarView }));


// 2.)  Or create a seperate model for each type of model?
var morgModel = morgModel.extend({});
var blarModel = blarModel.extend({});

gizmoCollection.add(new morgModel({ title: 'Gizmo1' });
gizmoCollection.add(new blarModel({ title: 'Gizmo2' });


// 3.  Or register 'types' of views?
gizmoView.subClassView('morg', morgView);
gizmoView.subClassView('blar', blarView);
gizmoCollection.add(new gizmoModel({ title: 'Gizmo1', type: 'morg' });
gizmoCollection.add(new gizmoModel({ title: 'Gizmo2', type: 'blar' });
```

Answer (score 1):

My choice would be to create separate models and it views if necessary. The reason is that each model should hold business logic for it self. Now, you may find sometimes easier to do this just with subviews if there is only presentational logic which is different for each model type or model attribute value.

You should keep in mind following:

1. Presentational logic goes to Presenter(s) (Backbone.View)
2. Business logic goest to model(s) (Backbone.Model)
3. Navigation logic either router (aka controller) or you can make your Event Bus from Backbone.Events or jQuery.callbacks() which will do this job and probably some other things which you want separate from your presenters and models.

Final note. Always keep in mind that your app will grow, sometimes it is wiser to add few more lines of code regardless you don't need so much complexity at the moment. But if you senses tell you that at some point that code will become more complex, well you should do it right away or later you will not have enough time.